# How to curve cube/rectangular prism along path? Problem with distortion

Tags: bezier-curves, edit-mode, extrude, distort

Ok, so basically I need to create a low poly cord, where the actual cross section of the cord is always the same square shape/size but it can turn/bend at angles as I choose to model it.

Ive looked/tried tutorials with extrude along path and similar questions but can't get any to work. Rotating various rectangular prisms and aggregating them is messy, and with just dragging the face out I get this distortion on the cross section:

[image]

With extrude from cube - only goes halfway :

[image]

What is the easiest/best way to achieve this?

Comment: Best way is a [bezier curve with a bevel object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale) or an [Array+Curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82413/create-constant-length-object-for-manipulation)

Comment: Doesn't work - see edit Ive tried with cube and flat plane and only fills one side